# How to fetch day, month and hour from NSDate in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I have an `NSDate` object called reservationDate and I want to fetch **day, month and hour** from the Date. However, I'm getting wrong values. How can I get these values?

The value of the reservationDate object 
reservationDate `NSDate` `2016-08-05 21:00:00 UTC`
thus I expect to get 5 as a day and 21 as a hour however I'm receiving 6 as a day and 0 as a hour. Should I expect something else?

```
let unitFlags: NSCalendarUnit = [.Hour, .Day, .Month, .Year]
let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(unitFlags, fromDate: reservationDate)
let day = components.day
let hour = components.hour
```

Comment: it gives UTC time formate

Comment: What result do you want? The hour as displayed on a wall clock in Greenwich (GMT/UTC) or the hour according to your location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set Time zone. Please assign it "UTC".

```
NSCalendar.currentCalendar().timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")!
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set timezone with `Calendar` object with `UTC`

```
let unitFlags: NSCalendarUnit = [.Hour, .Day, .Month, .Year]
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")!
let components = calendar.components(unitFlags, fromDate: NSDate())
let day = components.day
let hour = components.hour
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let currentDate = NSDate()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle
var convertedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm"
convertedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)
```